# Version incompatibility issue! ‘com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0’

Tags: android

There are errors that I can’t fix as seen in the picture.

[image: For image click or touch]

“Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX…”

[image: Photo 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the support library dependency and add the [material components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Comment: app isn't installed. The problem persists.